# Why is GCC doing this - is it standard - initializing array member with another array?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

OK imagine this code:

```
int a[3], a1[3] = a;
```

GCC complains

> error: invalid initializer

for `a`

*Which of-course could be implemented via extension without too much cost but that's another question.*

But then if we have an array inside a structure like this:

```
int a[3]; struct { char c; int b[3]; } d = { 9, a };
```

It's compiled fine with the following warning:

> warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]

Which means that `a` is decayed into a pointer in the initialization of `d`, which is then casted into integer and I assume using to fill the `d.b` array.

Is this default behavior?

I don't insist using code like this. Opposite - never do this. But I'm wondering how could the compiler handle this attempt of copying over an array so wrongly.

I'm using gcc 6.1.1.

Comment: This is a victim of "brace elision", and is behavior according to the Standard. `a` here initializes `d.b[0]`, which gcc allows with a warning. Of course, since your code will be invalid anyway, the fact it's brace elision is kind of irrelevant from a lawyer's point of view, but that's what happens.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb OK - I think I understand now.

Comment: I don't think I'll ever get why C programmers insist on writing code that is as impenetrable as possible. Is there some kind of secret society that takes care of getting retired C programmers back in touch with the victims that have to maintain their code?  I feel left out, I want to be a member too.

Comment: @HansPassant Me too. I assume it's part the compilers fault though allowing confusing code like this to exist on the first place. Especially when your intentions are obvious as in the case I clearly want to copy initialize array with another array but my compiler decides to implicitly make this wrong code work by some fancy user friendly 'extension'. And futher-more make it work in some totally un-expected way.

Comment: The most important thing to understand here is that you never got anywhere close to "initializing an array with another array", because `a`, when used as an initializer, is a pointer, just like it would be in most expression contexts.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley But it would be handy neat feature - don't you think? Currently the only way to get near is using unnamed union with the array member second member (and the first the same array wrapped into structure). Though it is still a solution but at the time I was writing the question I wasn't there yet plus it was confusing to me how code like this would work in all this wrong way.

Comment: My tips are: 1. Don't expect any operations to work on an array-as-a-whole without calling a function; arrays don't like to be handled as big lumps, they like to be pointed at. 2. Never put "compiled fine" next to "makes integer from pointer without a cast"! That warning means the code is definitely not fine!

Comment: `b[0]` gets initialise with `&a[0]` "*make[ing] integer from pointer without a cast*".

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, both of those initializations are constraint violations. Never in C can a pointer be converted to an integer without a cast.

Unfortunately (IMHO), gcc and other compilers sometimes go on to generate an executable, pretending that you wrote a cast where you didn't.

Maybe some people find this convenient,  but as evinced by the number of related posts on this site and others, it confuses beginners who see the word "warning" and think "oh it's just a warning, not a mistake in my code";  or perhaps don't see the diagnostic at all (e.g. some online compilers don't even show warnings) and go on to wonder why their program produces unexpected output.

I don't know the exact inner workings of gcc that lead to different diagnostics for these two cases, but compiling with `-Werror` or `-Werror-int-conversion` should prevent the compiler from generating an executable in this case.